# qunit return unit test

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

Is there a way for Qunit to return the test it just current ran. I am new to QUnit. The callback Qunit.log only returns the message, result, actual, expected. But I want the original code used. The actual unit test created. I am creating a website that lets user write unit tests as normal strings for a specified function and my website runs it. But if the user decides to compound unit tests like:

```
var a = 1; 
var b = 2; 
 function plus(a,b) { return a + b; } equal(plus(a,b), 3); equal( 1 == '2', 'Fail!' );
```

Then Qunit will run the test individually, but just says pass or fail for each unit test, however does not give the actual code ran. I can use backend to keep track of the string input, but I was wondering if anybody knew an easy way for Qunit to tell me:

> "I ran test x, result was Y, message was W, actual was A, etc"

Answer (score 0):

equal() or ok() can take a message as a parameter. For example,

`ok (1 == 1, "One equals one.");`

Does that help? Seems like you could maybe automate the message using your string parsing skillz.